# Foam coming out around window

Tags: windows

I noticed this foam stuff coming out from around the outside of my window. It’s about a quarter inch in width and is coming out of a small groove. I’m a noob at house stuff so I have no idea what this is or if it’s important. Can anyone tell me if I should replace it and how do I go about doing that? Thanks.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a sliding window. That's part of the seal between windows.
It allows one pane to pass over the other, but seals the 2 panes when the window is closed.

It has failed and will need to be replaced.

Comment: Thanks. What would this be called when I'm searching for a replacement?

Comment: @Andrey Using <your favorite search engine> to search for images of [`brush weather stripping`](https://www.google.com/search?q=brush+weather+stripping&tbm=isch) should turn up some suitably fuzzy candidates.

Comment: Another name is "pile weatherstripping" (I guess because it has pile like carpet).